# jquery click off event element to switch image back to default

Tags: jquery

I currently have an image that changes when you click it but when I click on another image I would like it to return back to its default image state.

the code I have so far is below.

```
$('a img.lrg').click(function(){
  var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("largefont.gif", "largefonton.gif");
  $(this).attr("src", newSrc); 
});
```

How can I change this to do the desired effect?

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to hold the old src

```
$('a img.lrg').click(function(){
  $('a img.lrg').each(function(index, item){
     if($(item).data('old-src') != undefined){
          $(item).attr('src', $(item).data('old-src')); // bring back old image
     }
  })
  var old_src = $(this).attr("src");
  $(this).data('old-src', old_src);
  var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("largefont.gif", "largefonton.gif");
  $(this).attr("src", newSrc); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/94CqN/

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery's blur() function. http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("src", "largefonton.gif");
```

Will this help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a img').click(function(){
  var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("largefonton.gif", "largefont.gif");
  $(this).attr("src", newSrc); 
});
```

you could add a global action for all a>img tags, put this before your $('a img.lrg').click(function(){ jquery otherwise it will run after

that or you could use a mouse event, that if you move away from the pic (you can put this anywhere)

```
  $('a img').mouseout(function(){
      var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("largefonton.gif", "largefont.gif");
      $(this).attr("src", newSrc); 
    });
```

Or you could set a unique ID to the img tag: so you select via a img.className#unqiueID  id set on page load or via some random variable